# How to get data and display in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

So I have my Interface, View Model, and Repository in one file. I am trying to display users from https://dummyjson.com/users but I'm having difficulty with how to setup up the Api Service & How to implement the view model in UI.

```
package com.example.memberlist

import androidx.lifecycle.*
import com.example.memberlist.DataSource.User
import com.example.memberlist.DataSource.Users
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiConverterFactory
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Path

private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://dummyjson.com/")
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
    .build()

object UserApi {
    val retrofitService: UserService by lazy { retrofit.create(UserService::class.java) }
}

interface UserService{
    @GET("/users/{id}")
    suspend fun getUser(@Path("id") id :Int): User

    @GET("/users")
    suspend fun getAllUsers():Users
}

class UserRepository constructor(
    private val userService: UserService
) {
    suspend fun getUser(id: Int): User {
        return userService.getUser(id)
    }

    suspend fun getAllUsers():Users{
        return userService.getAllUsers()
    }
}



class UserViewModel: ViewModel() {

    private val users = MutableLiveData<Users>()
    val user = users as LiveData<Users>

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                // Calling the repository is safe as it will move execution off
                // the main thread
                val user = UserApi.retrofitService.getAllUsers()
                users.value = user
            } catch (error: Exception) {
                //
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have already managed to make the data classes by using the Json to Kotlin Plugin on Android Studio to convert the json to their data class counterparts

```
data class ApiDataX(
    val limit: Int,
    val skip: Int,
    val total: Int,
    val users: List<User>
)

data class User(
    val address: Address,
    val age: Int,
    val bank: Bank,
    val birthDate: String,
    val bloodGroup: String,
    val company: Company,
    val domain: String,
    val ein: String,
    val email: String,
    val eyeColor: String,
    val firstName: String,
    val gender: String,
    val hair: Hair,
    val height: Int,
    val id: Int,
    val image: String,
    val ip: String,
    val lastName: String,
    val macAddress: String,
    val maidenName: String,
    val password: String,
    val phone: String,
    val ssn: String,
    val university: String,
    val userAgent: String,
    val username: String,
    val weight: Double
)
```

The next one is the MainActivity all comoposable stuff.

```
package com.example.memberlist

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.CircleShape
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.BasicTextField
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.material.ButtonDefaults.buttonColors
import androidx.compose.material.ButtonDefaults.elevation
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.livedata.observeAsState
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.rememberSaveable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.clip
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.shadow
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.RectangleShape
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.layoutId
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel
import com.example.memberlist.DataSource.User
import com.example.memberlist.ui.theme.MemberListTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MemberListTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme

            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Screen() {

    val viewModel: UserViewModel = viewModel()

    val users by viewModel.user.observeAsState()

    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ){
        Column(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp)){

            Spacer(Modifier.height(10.dp))
            Head()
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(15.dp, 10.dp)
            ){
                items(100){
                    Item()
                }
            }
        }

    }
}

@Composable
fun UserList(){

}

@Composable
fun Item(){
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(10.dp)
            .layoutId("box")
    ){
        Row(
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(50.dp),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ){
            CircleImage()
            Column(
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(5.dp)
            ){
                Text(
                    text = "John Doe",
                    fontFamily = FontFamily.SansSerif,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight(500)
                )
                Button(
                    onClick = {},
                    contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 40.dp, vertical = 0.dp),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .border(1.dp, Color.Red, RectangleShape)
                        .height(30.dp),
                    colors = buttonColors(
                        backgroundColor = Color.Transparent
                    ),
                    elevation = elevation(
                        defaultElevation = 0.dp,
                        pressedElevation = 0.dp,
                        disabledElevation = 0.dp,
                        hoveredElevation = 0.dp,
                        focusedElevation = 0.dp
                    )
                ){
                    Text(
                        text = "Follow",
                        color = Color.Red
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun CircleImage(){
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.habesha_guy_11),
        contentDescription = null,
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(75.dp)
            .clip(CircleShape)
    )
}

@Composable
fun Head(){
    Column() {
        SearchField("Search ...")
        RowSelection()
    }
}

@Composable
fun RowSelection(){

    Box(
        modifier= Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(10.dp),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterEnd
    ){
        Row(
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
            modifier = Modifier
                .horizontalScroll(
                    rememberScrollState(),
                    true,
                    null
                )
        ){
            Text(
                text="All",
                color = Color.DarkGray,
            )
            Text(
                text="Groups",
                color = Color.DarkGray,
            )
            Text(
                text="People",
                color = Color.DarkGray,
            )
            Text(
                text="Photos",
                color = Color.DarkGray,
            )
            Text(
                text="Videos",
                color = Color.DarkGray,
            )
            Text(
                text="Pages",
                color = Color.DarkGray,
            )
            Text(
                text="Places",
                color = Color.DarkGray,
            )
            Text(
                text="Groups",
                color = Color.DarkGray,
            )
            Text(
                text="Events",
                color = Color.DarkGray,
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(20.dp))
        }
    }

}

@Composable
fun SearchField(
    hint: String
){
    val txt = rememberSaveable() {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .heightIn(min = 45.dp, max = 50.dp),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ){
        BasicTextField(
            value = txt.value,
            onValueChange = {txt.value = it},
            modifier = Modifier
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(30.dp))
                .fillMaxWidth(0.8f)
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .shadow(1.dp, RoundedCornerShape(30.dp), true),
            maxLines = 1,
            singleLine = true
        ){
            if(txt.value.isEmpty())
                Text(
                    text = hint,
                    color = Color.DarkGray,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .offset(20.dp, y = 15.dp)
                )

            /*
                SEARCH ICON

            Icon(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_baseline_search_24),
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(16.dp)
                    .offset(x = 100.dp)
            )

            */
        }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true, showSystemUi = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    MemberListTheme {
        Screen()
    }
}
```

Here is how the UI looks in Picture, am using res/drawable image

[UI image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQQiI.png)

Can someone help use the dummyjson.com/users to display on the UI. How to setup the ViewModel, Interface, and Repository and How to implement the ViewModel on a composable?